# Interpretation requested

Tags: c#, caching

Can someone kindly point me to an explanation, if there is one, to this chunk of code and what it does and why? Specifically the bottom line...

```
protected uint uMask;
int nBits = (int)Math.Log(BlockSize, 2);
uMask = 0xffffffff << nBits;
```

For instance, on the first iteration BlockSize is 8, nBits is 3 and after the operation, the uMask is 4294967288.

I tried Googling the third line as I don't know how to put this into plain language, and I got examples of code and that is not what I was looking for.

Comment: `<<` is a bitshift aka `*2^nBits`

Comment: @ratchetfreak is right. You shift the Bits in 0xffffffff 2^n Bytes in the left direktion.

Comment: Look at all of the numbers in binary or hex, it will make a lot more sense than in base 10.

Comment: @Servy, I don't know what you just said...

Comment: @Risho Look at the numbers in base 2 or base 16, rather than base 10.  "Binary" is a term for base 2, an "hexadecimal", often called "hex" is a term for a particular style of base 16 in which A-F represent values 11 through 16.

Comment: @mri, can you somehow elaborate on that 2^n in the left direction? Do I substitute 3, which then is 8? For example if you were doing the calculation on paper, what would it look like? Thanks!

Comment: While it is true that `<<` is identical to multiplying by a power of two, it is misleading to think this way as it is typically used when the intent is to move bits around for purposes other than mathematical manipulation.

Comment: This sort of reminds me the beginning of Month Python and the Holy Grail when the two guards are discussing the coconuts and their method for migration, rather then allowing King Arthur enter. Sorry to say none of these are answers I asked for. :/

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be creating a mask to exclude bits from a larger structure.  Some piece of data is probably stored in a larger value and has a maximum value `Blocksize`.  This code determines how many bits are required for that item, given its maximum value in `Blocksize`.  It then uses this number of bits to create a mask.  After the last line, `uMask` will look something like this in binary (assuming `Blocksize` is 8 and `nBits` is 3:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000
```

or in hex:

```
0xfffffffc
```

This would typically be used to remove one field stored in piece of data in order to isolate some other field.  Conceptually, you might have bits used for value A and value B in a 64 bit value:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBB
```

Suppose you want to get the value for A.  You could do something like this:

```
result = value & uMask;     // Step 1: Mask off B
result = result >> nBits    // Step 2:Align A
```

Data will look like this:

```
Step 1:     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA000
Step 2:     000AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Unless you have a savant math ability, you're never going to be able to read masks in decimal.